# dependent true in hasMany not working on children nodes in cakephp4

Tags: php, tree, has-many, cakephp-4.x

I have a CategoriesTable using TreeBehavior and hasMany Articles :

```
class CategoriesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->addBehavior('Tree');
        $this->belongsTo('Categories');
        $this->hasMany('Articles', [
            'dependent' => true
        ]);
    }
 }
```

When I delete a category "C" that contains articles, the articles are correctly deleted as I have set dependent on true.
However, if I delete the parent of category "C", articles in "C" are not deleted any more.
I thought "cascadeCallbacks" would help to fix that, but it doesn't...

It's weird because in Cakephp2 it worked.

How can I do to tell CakePHP to delete all the articles contained in any deleted category or subcategories ?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't surprise too much that things aren't the same anymore as in 2.x, as basically the whole ORM layer has been replaced.

What happens here is that the tree behavior will delete the child nodes of the category when the `Model.beforeDelete` event is dispatched. This happens before any association delete operations do run, and for performance reasons it is being done using a single `DELETE` query, which won't trigger any callbacks.

So by the time any association delete operations do run, there already is no category `C` anymore, as it was already deleted for being a child node of category `B`.

There's various way this could be handled, you could for example create proper foreign key constraints in the DB that will delete the linked article records (this will of course circumvent any application level delete functionality), or make it set the foreign key to `NULL`, and then run a second delete operation that deletes the orphaned articles, where you could then decide whether you do this in a single delete query without callbacks, or if you delete the article entities one by one.

There's certainly more ways, but I don't think that it will get any prettier, for example you could obtain all child nodes first, then disable the tree behavior, delete all category entities one by one so that the cascading association delete operations do run, then enable the tree behavior again, and finally recover the tree... very ugly, possible performance killer, do not recommend, I probably shouldn't even have mentioned it!

You could of course also create an issue over at GitHub for a feature request that would allow to *optionally* delete tree child nodes one by one so that callbacks are triggered. For small trees this could be a viable option.